# IIS 6.0 DirectoryEntry properties list

Tags: .net, iis-6

I'm new to accessing IIS 6.0 using C# code. I'm using DirectoryEntry to set properties in IIS, but would like to have better understandig of what properties that I can access, and how.

So if any of you have experiance using DirectoryEntry to access IIS 6.0, and know of a propertie list or a good staring point, can you help a new guy out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find a list of all MetaBase properties [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525644.aspx).  Note not all properties apply to all object types, the property documentation lists the object types that the property applies to.

If you look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524997.aspx), you can see a list of all the object types applicable to IIS and each lists which properties are valid for the type and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525994.aspx) you can see the structure for object types containing other object types.

Answer (score 3):

The following code may be used to retrieve properties for your case...

```
DirectoryEntry dir = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/" + siteid + "/root");
        foreach (string elmentName in dir.Properties.PropertyNames)
        {
            PropertyValueCollection valueCollection = dir.Properties[elmentName];
            for (int i = 0; i < valueCollection.Count; i++)
            {

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(elmentName + "[" + i.ToString() + "] =" + valueCollection[i].ToString() + "<br/>");
            }
        }
```

.